# Can I set the value of a cell using a custom function that refers to another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make a custom function for a spreadsheet I am making to track a fictional football league. What I need is to be able to convert a full name into an abbreviation so as to allow me to set up a system where the standings only need to check the results for "ABBR R" where R is a W (Win), L (Loss) or T (Tie). I know I can do this in normal excel using a nested if then else formula but I have sixteen teams to check and it would be horrendously inefficient.

```
=If(C6="Arizona Vipers","ARZ",If(C6="Atlanta Warriors","ATL",If(C6="Calgary Bandits","CGY",If(C6="Columbus Express","CLM",If(C6="Detroit Firebirds","DET",If(C6="Hartford Minutemen","HFD",If(C6="Montreal Bucks","MTL",If(C6="New Jersey Sharks","NJ",If(C6="Portland Beavers","POR",If(C6="Salt Lake City Rams","SLC",If(C6="San Antonio Knights","SA",If(C6="San Diego Sailors","SD",If(C6="St. Louis Eagles","STL",If(C6="Toronto Bulls","TOR",If(C6="Vancouver Timberwolves","VAN",If(C6="Vegas Aces","VEG",""))))))))))))))))
```

I tried making a VBA to see if I could get it to recognize one team using this method.

```vb
Function checkTeam(a)
    Dim abbr As String
    Set abbrCell = Application.ThisCell
    currCell = Application.ThisCell
    If a = "Arizona Vipers" Then
        currCell.Value = "ARZ"
    End If
End Function
```

I expect the cell with the checkTeam function to get changed to the abbr, "ARZ" in this case but I get no output. I'm not that good at VBA and I know I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

A function used on a worksheet can only return a value to the worksheet.  Typically you'd just do something like this:

```
Function checkTeam(a)
    If a = "Arizona Vipers" Then
        checkTeam = "ARZ"
    End If
End Function
```

This does seem like something you could do more easily with a lookup table and VLOOKUP though

Answer (score 0):

as Tim said, a custom function only impacts a cell (with a few bizarre exceptions).

In case his answer isn't clear... this function would would probably get you what you want. The input value would be a cell with the full name.

```
Function checkTeam(theFullName) As String
    Dim tName As String: tName = theFullName

    If InStr(1, tName, "Atlanta", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        checkTeam = "ATL"

    ElseIf InStr(1, tName, "Arizona", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        checkTeam = "ARZ"

    'etc etc
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim is right.  The natural way to do this in Excel is to set up a lookup table and put a vlookup formula in to translate your full team name into the abbreviation.

Typically, set up a list in a separate sheet.

The gotcha's on vlookups are that you need the list sorted by the value you're comparing, and this must be the first column of the range that you specify.

If you use headers for this list, do not include them in the call to vlookup.

When specifying your lookup table use $ prefixes to prevent the range changing when you auto fill - eg LookupSheet!$A$2:$B$17

Remember that you are looking for a translation, so your last argument to vlookup should be FALSE to get an exact match.

Your formula for the abbreviation might then look like

=vlookup(c6,LookupSheet!$A$2:$B$17,2,False)